# How can we extract all the action rules of a project in one single excel from decision center IBM ODM

Tags: java, ibm-cloud, odm, ibm-odm, dc

I need to extract all the action rules in one single excel from decision center.Is there a way to do so?I have already deployed the study. I tried to select the rules and then export but it's extracting all the projects present.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.